# How to create temporary file/folder using public Gradle API?

Tags: file, junit, gradle, directory, temporary

From the Gradle's code I found that there are methods :
***TemporaryFileProvider*** and ***TestNameTestDirectoryProvider*** for creating temporary file and folder but they are not part of the public API.

```
org.gradle.api.internal.file.TemporaryFileProvider
org.gradle.test.fixtures.file.TestNameTestDirectoryProvider
```

If there any methods from the public *Gradle's API* that gives the user ability to create temporary files and folders and if not what are the best ways to do it?

PS. I use `org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder` for JUnit tests and Java's `File.createTempFile`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Task implementations can use `task.getTemporaryDir().createNewFile()`. What to use in JUnit tests isn't Gradle's business, but `org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder` would be my default choice.